# Are the MySQL Partitions visible in the EXPLAIN plan of a SELECT....?

Tags: mysql

I would like to know whether we have a chance to see what are the partitioned being scanned during the execution plan of the query.

Is this information in visible in the EXPLAIN/EXPLAIN EXTENDED of the respective SELECT...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use: [EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-info.html)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`EXPLAIN PARTITIONS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-info.html) (and [5.5 link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-info.html))

> Beginning with MySQL 5.1.5, it is possible to determine which partitions of a partitioned table are involved in a given SELECT query using EXPLAIN PARTITIONS. The PARTITIONS keyword adds a partitions column to the output of EXPLAIN listing the partitions from which records would be matched by the query.

From [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html), you can use `PARTITIONS` or `EXTENDED`, but not both

Comment: You have added another important info like the version from where this feature active.